# accessing a class from inside a gem

Tags: ruby, class, rubygems

i have created a gem locally by the name of "usersearch". 
Inside the lib folder, I have a "User" folder and a class named "User". 
I call the gem in to a ruby program and I want to create an object of "User" type. But the User class exists inside gem. How do i call it?

Comment: try to call it by doing ::User

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How do i call it?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 1):

When you load/require a file, it is always loaded in the main namespace regardless of where you load/require. If you defined `User` in a gem properly, and have required that gem, you should be able to refer to it by just writing `User` unless you have defined it in some namespace such as `Foo::User`.